# How can I read a subset of the images in the json file instead of the whole dataset?

Tags: python, json, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning; however, I have read images directly from a large dataset (349400 images) and fed to the model:

```
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(''))
        data = []
        labels =[]
        # loop over the image paths
        for imagePath in imagePaths:
            # extract the class label from the filename
            label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-4]
            image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
```

Now I have a json file that has a portion of this dataset (340191 images), and I want to read only the images in that file. What is the best way to approach this issue?
how can I select only the images in the json file?

Json file like this

```
{
    "CP": {
        "0": {
            "3131": [
                "0000.png",
                "0001.png",
                "0002.png",
                "0003.png",
```

Comment: You want to get the images from this json ??

Comment: I want to match images in a json file to images in a dataset. That is, I want to feed the model by images as they appear in the json file instead of as they appear in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I assume you need your answer for TensorFlow. So you can do the following.

```
# First get values from JSON
import json
with open('/content/ct_train.json', 'r') as file:
  values = json.load(file)

# First we get the image_paths and labels from values file
image_paths = []
image_labels = []
for label in values.keys():
  for folder in values[label].keys():
    for sub_folder in values[label][folder].keys():
      for images in values[label][folder][sub_folder]:
        image_paths.append('{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(label, folder, sub_folder, images))
        image_labels.append(label)

# In TensorFlow
'''
you can use tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices where the first argument
is (image_paths, image_labels) and then use a function to read the image
in the corresponding format.
'''

def read_img(image_paths, labels):
    bytefile = tf.io.read_file(image_paths)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bytefile) # use decode_png in case of png
    return img, labels

batch_size = 32
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, image_labels))
dataset = dataset.map(read_img).batch(batch_size)

model = create_model()
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

Here you will need to LabelEncode your image_labels and you can do that easily by yourself.

Comment: No, I want to take image name from json file then read it as png from dataset file

Comment: You just need to extract image_paths from your JSON. Just post your JSON and I will write the whole code.

Comment: https://github.com/arthursdays/HKBU_HPML_COVID-19/blob/master/covid19_pipeline/data/ccccii/ct_train.json , this is the JSON file, and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Rafa I have edited the answer. In my answer, I assumed that the structure of the folder to be as mentioned in the JSON file.

Comment: Since values is the name of a dictionary, why didn't you define it before using it?

Comment: @Rafa my bad I missed the copy paste.